# JPA criteria API : join table through third table (n:m relationship)

Tags: mysql, sql, jpa, join, criteria-api

I am trying to create a join with criteria api for the following problem: I have 2 tables lets call them A and C both of them has reference for table B and I would like to join them on that table, I tried something like that but is doest seems to be valid:

```
CriteriaQuery<A> query = cb.createQuery(A.class);
Root<A> root = query.from(A.class);
Join<A, C> join = root.join(A_.b);
```

The error message is:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Join<A,B> to Join<A,C>
```

Relevant part of the entities ( A and C):

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "B_ID")
private B b;
```

I haven't found a solution for that in the tutorials for using the criteria API. Anybody has idea how to do this kind of join?

Comment: You have to youn to `B` and then join to `C`. `Join<A, B> join = root.join(A_.b);Join<B, C> join1 = join.join(B_.c);` or somthink like that

Comment: B doesnt have reference for C so it is not working B_.c

Comment: Can you add a database description? or your objects A, B and C?

Comment: Both A and C contains id's for records of B. In the application for both table the field is annotated with ManyToOne

Comment: Post the code of your entities.

Comment: posted relevant part of entity a and c